# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element' while trying to crawl subway.co.kr

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape subway store and create a table filled with addresses, names, and phone numbers. However, my code keeps giving error-filled results. Below is my code

```
import time
import requests
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.common.by   import By
from selenium.webdriver             import ActionChains
from bs4        import BeautifulSoup
from selenium   import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
url1 = 'http://subway.co.kr/storeSearch?page='
url2 = '&rgn1Nm=&rgn2Nm=#storeList'

addresses = []
names = []
phones = []

for i in range(41):
    driver.get(url1 + str(i) + url2)
    lst = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr')
    for row in lst:
        addresses.append(lst.find_element(By.XPATH, './td[2]/div/a').text)
        names.append(lst.find_element(By.XPATH, './td[1]/a').text)
        phones.append(lst.find_element(By.XPATH, './td[4]/div').text)

stores = [{
    'address'   : props[0],
    'name'      : props[1],
    'phone'     : props[2]
} for props in zip(addresses, names, phones)]

with open('stores.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvout = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, ['address', 'name', 'phone'])
    csvout.writeheader()
    csvout.writerows(stores)
```

so how do I access each elements(address, name, phone) in each row? I am also adding an image of a page of set of pages I am trying to crawl.

[image: subway page of store infos]

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `find_element` on the list object, I suspect you want to to use `row` instead, which are the elements you a looping over. Change

```
addresses.append(lst.find_element(
```

to

```
addresses.append(row.find_element(
```

And the same for `names` and `phones`